# Binary to Decimal conversion in Python

Tags: python, binary, type-conversion, decimal

I tried binary to decimal conversion in Python and I found this code:

```py
t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n=int(input(),2)
    print(n)
```

This gives the right output but I am not able to understand the workflow of this code

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is unclear to you? Have you read the relevant docs? Any tutorials?

Comment: I am not able to understand its workflow @jonrsharpe

Comment: First you have an input, then a loop. Do you understand what `t = int(input())` does?

Comment: What do you mean by *"workflow"*? Have you tried any debugging? Maybe try e.g. http://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int() function in Python and Python3 converts a number in given base to decimal.
So,in your code:
the first line is for asking the user whether how many binary numbers he wants to convert to decimal.
Then you are setting the range in for loop.
Then you are asking for input with base 2 to convert that to decimal and printing it.
So,proper code would be:

```
t=int(input("Enter how many numbers you want to convert to decimal:"))
for _ in range(t):
    n=int(input("Enter the number"),2)
    print(n)
```